# Using the adb root command

Tags: android, adb

The 'adb root' command's description says that it restarts the adbd with root permissions.

I tried it on my phone (Note 2 Android 4.3), which is not rooted, and it didn't work. I searched online, and I found that even on rooted devices, it can give error messages as "adbd cannot run as root in production builds".

My question is under what conditions will 'adb root' successfully restart adbd with root permissions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adb root` needs a development (aka debug) build with `ro.debuggable=1`

Comment: Hi @Alex, but where to set ro.secure=0, I am using only platform build tools on linux for accessing android phone.